# Как написать решение уравнения?

Tags: pascal, математика

```
|x| + 2*A = 0.
```

Дано уравнение. Переменную А мы задаем в [input.txt](http://input.txt). Пусть будет -1. Решения будет 2: 2 и -2. Решить я знаю как, но вот вопрос - я не знаю, как это занести в программу. В [output.txt](http://output.txt) должно быть вот это. В первой строке выходного файла выведите количество решений данного уравнения, а во второй через пробел сами решения.

В общем я присвоил переменной

```
у:=2*A
```

а потом

```
Z:=|x|*y
```

Но последнее неправильно. Подскажите, как записать, чтобы программа в оutput писала количество решений и решения. И как правильно составить уравнение.

А кстати вот и решение

```
|x|+2*-1=0;
```

`|x|-2=0;` меня интересует, как правильно записать эту строчку в программу.

```
x=2;
x=-2;
```

Comment: Текст глаза режет. Не надо все подряд делать наклонным шрифтом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задача не такая простая как кажется на первый взгляд.
Правда, если уравнение всегда одно и то же, то все много проще.

**Легкий способ**(количество уравнений ограничено)

```
var equation: string;
//...здесь считываем из файла параметр А
read(equation);
case equation of
"|x| + 2*A = 0":
begin
  Z1 := -2*A;
  Z2 := -(-2*A);
  amount:=2;
  if Z1=Z2 then begin
    amount := 1;
  end;
end;
"x^2 - 8*A*A = 0":
begin
  Z1 := sqrt(8)*A;
  Z2 := -sqrt(8)*A;
  amount:=2;
  if Z1=Z2 then begin
    amount := 1;
  end;
end;
//...И так далее для каждого
end;
```

**Сложный способ:**(Если уравнение задает, например, учитель)
Честно - лень писать. =(
Копайте в сторону [обратной польской записи](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Обратная_польская_запись), соответственно, [стеков](http://cyberguru.ru/pascal/turbopascal-encyclopaedia-page23.html) и [рекурсии](http://rsc-team.ru/index.pl?rzd=2&group=lection&ind=13)
Вам нужно последовательно пробежаться по примеру(посимвольно по строке), раскрывая все скобки и учитывая приоритет знаков арифметики.

Answer (score 1):

Выразите `x` через `A` на бумажке. И запишите то же самое на Паскале.

Answer (score -1):

1. Если А < 0. то решений два: +2А и -2А.
2. Если А = 0. то решение одно, и это нуль.
3. Если А > 0. то решений нет.